# error "Not Found" while Javascript to Rails AJAX connection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have some simple Rails controller method. This method works in browser and displays "OK" string. But when I call it from JavaScript as AJAX method, error "Not Found" is displayed to log from JavaScript error method.Why ?

What I see in browser JS log is:

```
"jqXHR: [object Object]" application.js:3069
"textStatus: error" application.js:3070
"errorThrown: Not Found"
```

Thanks for responses:)

Coupons_Controler:

```
def get_value()
    #coupon_name = params[:param1]
    #@coupon = Coupon.get_price(coupon_name)

  #respond_to do |format|
      #format.js { render :layout=>false }
      #render text: "17.8, true";
      render text: "OK";
    #end
  end
```

Javascript script method:

```
function validateDiscountCouponIDAjax( sec1, sec2 ) {
                    if( typeof sec1 === 'undefined' || typeof sec2 === 'undefined' ){
                sec1 = 2;
                sec2 = 3;
            }

                    $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'http://localhost:3000/coupons/',
                            //data: $('discount_coupon_id').serialize(),
                            success: function(resp) {
                                    if (resp === 'OK') {                                        
                                        console.log('Validation ok');
                                        showMessage( true, 'Discount coupon validated!' );  
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            console.log('Response error: ' + resp);
                                            //$('#password-dialog-error').text(resp);
                                    }
                            },
                            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    var seconds = sec1 + sec2;
                    sec1 = sec2;
                    sec2 = seconds;

                    console.log('jqXHR: '+jqXHR);
                    console.log('textStatus: '+textStatus);
                    console.log('errorThrown: '+errorThrown);

                    var reconnectInterval = setInterval( function() {
                        changeMessage( false, 'Connection error. Trying to reconnect in ' + seconds + ' seconds.', false );
                        seconds--;

                        if( seconds <= 0 ) {
                            clearInterval( reconnectInterval );
                            hideMessage( 'fast' );
                            validateDiscountCouponIDAjax( sec1, sec2 );
                        }
                    }, 1000 );
                            }
                    });
            }
```

**ADDED**:
I found error in JS class:

**No route matches [POST] "/coupons"**

Why such error?

**ADDED 2: SOLVED!**
OK solved:), I was using GET in Route.rb, but AJAX was trying to do POST:). After changing both to GET , it works:)

Comment: What do the server logs have to say about this?

Comment: Im not sure how to find logs, Im using Ubuntu and I was analyzing logs port 80, but this is temporary instance created for/by Rails.  Where I can find logs in this situation?

Comment: Right where you ran `rails server`, the terminal session.

Comment: Added error message to problem description at the top:)

Comment: I changed POST to GET and it works:).. so the problem is with Route.rb:) BUt I want to use POST:)

Comment: Great job! Asnwer your own question then, it's perfectly legit.

Comment: You can accept my solution :) Thanks for efforts.

Comment: Accepting is up to the one who asked the question. It's how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 2):

**Found solution:**

JS AJAX method was using POST method

```
...
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://localhost:3000/coupons/',
...
```

But in Route.rb: URL was define as GET method

```
get 'coupons' => 'coupons#get_value', :as => :coupons
```

**So the solution is to change in both places to GET or POST value.**